# Show 404 on page for node path url instead of redirecting to it's alias

Tags: 8, path-aliases, redirection

I'm currently using the Redirect module in Drupal 8 along with Pathauto to create aliases on all url's.  So for example /node/23 would be /article/some-text-here.  When a user types in /node/23 in the url it automatically redirects them to the alias url.  I want to show a 404 whenever the user uses the node path url instead of redirecting that way they don't ever have a chance to find something they shouldn't by traversing through my site with that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The rabbit_hole module can be used to set 'access' controls for rendered nodes, taxonomies, and other entities.  When a user visits the /node/*  or /taxonomy/term/* page, you can control what happens--403 page, 404 page, redirect, whatever.  This can also be overridden on a per-node basis if you require that.

https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole

This still allows the entities to be accessible via path alias and shouldn't break any references to those nodes/taxonomies.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure apache `mod_alias` is enabled and create a rule in `.htaccess` like:

```
Redirect 404 /node/.*$
```

Comment: this had no effect.  I tried RewriteRule ^/?node/[^a-zA-Z_]+$ redir_path [L,R=301] and it worked but I want to display the 404 instead of redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

I would also try this, although this would apply for Drupal 7

```
$path = current_path();
if($path == 'node/23') {
   drupal_not_found();
}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer - original question is asking for a scalable solution, not hardcoded. Also, this won't work for Drupal 8.

Comment: I have made an edit as to suggest for drupal 7.